# Why my responsive CSS don't work for mobile devices

Tags: css

Why does only the 1000px breakpoint of these responsive designs activate when the toggle device toolbar is not enabled?

They all work by simply resizing the width, but only the 1000px one works on mobile devices or with the browser's Toggle Device Toolbar enabled

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        background-image: url('images/background-square.jpg');
        font-size: 0.9em;
        margin-top: 200px;
    }
    h1 {
        max-width: 60%;
    }
    #index-div p {
        max-width: 60%;
    }
    nav img {
        height: 70px;
        margin-left: 4%;
    }
    ul li a {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
        background-image: url('images/background-mobile.jpg');
    }
    h1 {
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
    
    #index-div p {
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    nav img {
        height: 45px;
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
    ul li a {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 470px) {
    nav img {
        height: 35px;
        margin-top: 2%;
        margin-left: 1%;
    }
    nav {
        height: 80px;
    }
    
    body {
        margin-top: -80px; 
    }
    form {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    .option {
        margin-left: 18%;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    nav img {
        display: none;
    }
    input {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

I've tried this writing the properties this way `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)`, also try isolating just one breakpoint with 768px, both didn't work

The browser completely ignores the CSS when on mobile devices, despite obeying when I simply resize the PC window

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with this CSS code. You need to use the browser inspector to help you work out what's going on. (For Apple devices you can either use the iOS Simulator, or you can plug your phone into your computer with a USB cable; in either case, the Develop menu on your Mac will show the device and allow you to start the inspector). If you want further help from the community, please edit your question to include a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Try this: @media screen and (max-width: 768px)

Comment: "@media screen and (max-width: 768px)" havent worked too

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you want to create styles for the following intervals

```
1px - 400px
401px - 470px
471px - 700px
701px - 1000px
```

For each interval except the lowest one, you need a `min-width` to separate it from the lower one. Otherwise the rules work for a higher interval also work for a lower intervel. For example for the 401px - 470px, you need to have it like this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 470px)
```

You can actually specify the minimum width except for the lowest interval

```
@media screen and (min-width: 401px)
```

Comment: damn still have the exact same problem

Comment: Could you put your code in a fiddle so we can look at it?